# How to call functions in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

Hello guys this is my code in the server side of socket.io and I don't know how to call this functions in the client side. Can you help me or provide me the code on how to call this functions:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

    sub.on('subscribe', function (channel) {
        pub.publish('Privatex','Test Message 1');
        pub.publish('Privatex','Test Message 2');
        pub.publish('Privatex','Test Message 3');
    });

    sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
        console.log(channel + ':' + message);
            sub.unsubscribe();
            pub.end();
            sub.end();
    });

    sub.incr('Channel Test');
    sub.incr('Privatex');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consult the [How-To-Use](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) section first.

To invoke this code on client side, you simply have to use this code, assuming socket.io is already configured on server side.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');//path to socket.io
</script>
```

But let' take two minutes to see what's going on : this will be invoked on EVERY client connection because it's directly under the `connection` event. It's sometimes not the best way to do this (because a client can be briefly disconnected), and it's better to emit events from the client.

**client code**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');//path to socket.io
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
</script>
```

**server code**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
   //do something here
  });
});
```